# How can I safely prepare bones for crafts?

Tags: safety, preparation, bone

Out in rural country, it's pretty easy to come across animal bones, especially skulls.

If I wanted to have them on display, or carve them, what's the best way to make sure they're safe to have out? That is, to make sure they're sanitary and won't rot over the years.

Comment: I've never done it, but I've heard that lye will eat everything fleshy (except the bones), but you have to be really careful with it (for obvious reasons), and rinse it off multiple times afterwards.  They're starting to use it for 'green' burials.  (and then they pulverize the bones to dust so you have something like ashes)

Comment: Are these skulls already clean or are they still... meaty?

Comment: @Catija Pretty much bleached by the sun and picked clean by critters. I dunno about germs and inside, like marrow

Comment: Hmmm... I'd always been under the impression that the UV light from the sun was a great killer of germs but, as you note, there could be other stuff on the inside.

Comment: There was an answer on this that was a link to a very informational site with details about best treatments for skeletons in different conditions (how much flesh was still there)-- I had commented that it'd be good to summarize it, in case of link rot ... but now it's been deleted, so there's no link at all.  Can anyone with high enough rep see the deleted post to copy the link?

Comment: @Joe It was a link-only answer that was removed accordingly, but the link was  jakes-bones.com if you'd care to make that information into an answer.

Comment: @CreationEdge : then convert it to a comment ( http://www.jakes-bones.com/p/how-to-clean-animal-bones.html ), or downvote it ... the link itself had good info, and I'd rather people have access to it than not have it at all.  And I don't want reputation for someone else's answer; if you undelete it, let me know, and I'll edit it so they get the rep.

Comment: @Joe Policy is to delete link only answers.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/287266 The OP can still try again.

Comment: @Catija if solar UV can kill surface germs, it still can't kill germs inside cavities, of which skulls have plenty.

Comment: @ChrisH I said that...

Answer (score 1):

Any bones which are obviously clean and free form any residual soft tissue shouldn't be too much of a problem. With skulls you obviously have more cavities to work about but if the outer surface is clean when you find it it is reasonable to amuse that the interior is too.

Once the bones are cleaned of any soil etc a wash with dilute hydrogen peroxide should effectively sterilise them without damaging the bone.

Obviously with any organic material of unknown origin you can never say it is 100% safe but equally it is ether practical or desirable to attempt to live in an aseptic world. For carving bones sensible precautions wold include wearing a dust mask (if using abrasives or power tools) and maintaining sensible hygiene in you work area. Similarly sealing your finished carving with oil, wax or lacquer should be effective in making it safe to display.

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide is a debriding agent, it is not a sterilizing or antiseptic agent. Any other recommendations to ensure it's sanitary?

Comment: @CreationEdge It's widely used as a disinfectant [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide#Disinfectant) though quite a high concentration may be needed.